# Cannot resolve symbol 'NotificationCompat ' in android studio 3.4.1

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-support-library

I am newer to Android and receive the error message: "NotificationCompat cannot be resolved to a type"

MinSDK=18, TargetSDK=28, Android Gradle Plugin Version=3.4.1, gradle version=5.1.1    how to solve this error help me guys

**My gradle file given below**

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-2'
   'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
}
```

**code with the error of notificationCompat**

```
  protected android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Action getStopAction() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WIFI_AP_ACTION_STOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return new android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Stop", pendingIntent).build();
```

Comment: I guess it is: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.. v4.. not v7. Build gradle is OK... but in the Java side, package path is wrong..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite you have `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` in your build gradle, the class path is `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action` (not `v7.app...`)

You can also confirm [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Action) (Note the V4 on the package path).

So, just update your method to:

```
protected android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Action getStopAction() { ... }
```

Answer (score 5):

For sdk 28 you need use: 
java.lang.Object
   ↳    androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat